# Prevent Rails console from removing consecutive linebreaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, irb

I'd like to prevent the Rails console from removing consecutive linebreaks:

```
CoolApp (PRODUCTION) > a = '
CoolApp (PRODUCTION) " hi
CoolApp (PRODUCTION) " 
CoolApp (PRODUCTION) " 
CoolApp (PRODUCTION) " hi'
=> "\nhi\nhi"
```

Does anyone know how I can do it? The string above should be `"\nhi\n\n\nhi"`

Comment: Cannot reproduce, returns `"\nhi\n\n\nhi"` as expected on my machine in IRB with Ruby 3.2.2 and in the console of a new Ruby on Rails 7.0.7.2 app. You might need to provide more information about your setup.

Comment: Looks like maybe this is an issue that started in Ruby 2.7 and only when `--nomultiline` is used?

Comment: happy to provide any config values. Not sure why one would vote to close this.

Comment: Seems like it could be an IRB bug.  I can reproduce in Ruby 2.7 and greater if I use `--nomultiline` (same as `IRB.conf[:USE_MULTILINE] = false`).  What version of Ruby are you on and when you start the console is `IRB.conf[:USE_MULTILINE]` `nil` or `false`?

Comment: `IRB.conf[:USE_MULTILINE]` is false and we're on Ruby 3.2.2p53

Comment: You're using the `--nomultiline` option then.  Might be worth opening an issue in GitHub to ask about it.  I know they've had other issues with `--nomultiline` with [handling indents](https://github.com/ruby/irb/issues/524) and handling [concurrent consoles](https://github.com/ruby/irb/issues/510).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like entering a single space on each new line will preserve that line's linebreak :)